# Deleting lines from a file through stdin piping in bash

Tags: awk, sed, pipe

Using this script:

```
awk '{print $0"\t"NR}' test | grep NA | awk '{print $21}'
```

I get the line numbers in my file, having "NA" in them

```
326
399
672
1512
1734
1737
2212
```

Using **sed**, can I delete these lines from my file in the same command through standard input, by piping after the last awk command? If not, is there any way to do it in a simple way?

Comment: it would be better if you have posted a testable input fragment of your `test` file and the final result

Comment: yeah, please clarify if `grep -v 'NA' test` doesn't solve your requirement...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would it be too boring to just write this as one `awk` command?

```
awk '!/NA/' test
```

The default action is to `print` the whole line, so this is the same as `!/NA/ { print $0 }` and would print any line that doesn't contain `NA`.

Answer (score 5):

The simpler way is to use only `sed`:

```
sed '/NA/d' test >test.new
```

If you want to do in-place editing with GNU `sed` (this will modify the file `test`):

```
sed -i '/NA/d' test
```

The `sed` expression `/NA/d` will apply the `d` command on all lines in the input that matches the regular expression `NA`.  The `d` command deletes lines.

---

If the line numbers were *all* you had, then the following would have worked too:

```
some_command | sed 's/$/d/' | sed -f /dev/stdin test >output
```

where `some_command` generates the line numbers that you'd like to delete from the file `test`.

The first `sed` turns the stream of numbers into a `sed` script by adding a `d` to each line.  A line reading `100d` would be interpreted as "delete line 100". This is then fed to the second `sed` as the actual script (it's reading the script via `/dev/stdin`) and it is applied to the file `test`.

The equivalent thing in a shell that knows about process substitutions:

```
sed -f <( some_command | sed 's/$/d/' ) test >output
```

But this is sillyness if you just want to delete lines containing the string `NA`.